# How do I share "advanced filters" in OpenERP 6.1?

Tags: odoo

How do I share "advanced filters" in OpenERP 6.1? Is there some way to have GLOBAL advanced filters that everyone can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Their no direct way you can do this but alternate way is :

Create Filter and Goto "Settings/Customization/Low Level Objects/Actions/Filters"
Now Duplicate the filter and Change user of the new duplicate filter

But this does works Perfect with OpenERP 7.0 as You need.

Thank You

Comment: Duplicating the filter at "Settings/Customization/Low Level Objects/Actions/Filters" works with OpenERP 6.1.1; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In OpenERP 6.1, go to the "filters" drop-down list and select "manage filters". Then click on the one you want to share globally to display its form view. Then, empty the "User" field. This will make this filter available to all users.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; and about OpenERP, elegant solution!

Comment: Oops, I just got around to testing your suggestion @Fabrice in OpenERP 6.1.1 and discovered that filters with no user disappear. I had to go to "Settings/Customization/Low Level Objects/Actions/Filters" and restore the user so it would appear for that user.

Answer (score 0):

in class ir_filters(osv.osv):

Change this function to read.

```
def get_filters(self, cr, uid, model):
    act_ids = self.search(cr,uid,[('model_id','=',model),'|',('user_id','=',uid),('user_id','=',False)])
    my_acts = self.read(cr, uid, act_ids, ['name', 'domain','context'])
    return my_acts
```

Then leave the user blank